# Rails: combine results from two categories into one list for view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, list, categories

An article can belong to many stories. Let's say 'politics' and 'economy'. Want to display a single list of related articles below article. Currently have it returning, in two blocks:

```
Latest Politics Articles
  1. Politics Link
  2. Politics Link
  3. Politics Link

Latest Economy Articles
  1. Economy Link
  2. Economy Link
  3. Economy Link
```

How do I combine the results in a single list?

```
Latest Politics & Economy Articles
  1. Politics Link
  2. Economy Link
  3. Economy Link
  4. Politics Link
  5. Etc.
```

The code for the article blocks is currently:

```
<% @article.stories.each do |story| %>
  <h3><%= story.story %></h3>
  <ul style="margin-left: 15px;">
    <% story.articles.lastfive.each do |article| %> 
      <li><span class="listing-update-slug"><%= link_to article.headline, article</span></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE:** Article model:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
has_and_belongs_to_many :regions
has_and_belongs_to_many :stories
belongs_to :type
has_many :newsitems
has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
```

…plus a couple of method and a bunch of scopes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a scope and delegate that problem to ActiveRecord:

In article model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
...
:by_stories, -> (s){ joins(:stories).where("stories.id = ?", s)}
...
end
```

In controller:

```
...
def related_articles
   Article.by_stories(@article.stories.pluck(:id)).where.not(id: @article.id)
end
...
```

Comment: Doesn't work.:

`PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column articles.story does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."story"...`

Comment: Can you share article.rb model?

Comment: I have edited the answer. I checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042296/trying-to-create-a-scope-in-rails-3-for-has-habtm-relationship for that kind of relationship. If you are not using rails 4 check the sintax for rails 3.

Comment: Nope. Returns: `undefined method `id' for #<Story::ActiveRecord`

Comment: I used pluck to get the ids of the stories and then pass them to the scope, now should work.

Comment: Hmmm, getting there, maybe. Doesn't break articles belonging to only one story, but need to be able to pass it an array of story ids, because each article could belong to several. It breaks on multi-story article pages.

Comment: When do you have a article with only one story you are passing an array of only one story id, it should work. Maybe the "where.not(id: @article.id)" is wrong? Are you receiving an error or just the query not return anything?

Comment: Hmmm, don't know, will go for a run and think about it. An article can have several stories (politics, economy, Podemos, etc) and each story then returns the latest X articles from that story. It works up to there. But what I'm trying to do is mash the results of the first two parts into a single list for the reader, instead of two or three separate ones.